# Retrofit2 call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() is not working in android 9 and crash the app without any Error in the logcat

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm Parsing some data from the server by Retrofit2. In other versions of Android and emulator, it is working fine. But the problem is it is not working in Android 9 (Pie) and Android Oreo (8.1). For this reason, the app is going to crash every time I installed. Another problem is, it's not showing any Error in the Logcat. So what can be the solution?

By reading some blogs and Stack Overflow, I have tried by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the `AndroidManifest`. I have also added the below file in the `AndroidManifest`.

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

where **network_security_config file** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">116.203.27.235/</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Here is the request code I made:

```
ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<ServerResponse> call = api.getServerResult(new String(encodeValue));

call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ServerResponse> call, @NonNull Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.message());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ServerResponse server = response.body();
            Log.i(TAG, "response callback");
            if (server != null) {
                for (Result result : server.getResults()) {
                    Log.i("server", result.getHostName());
                    Log.i("server", result.getIP());
                    Log.i("server", result.getScore());
                    Log.i("server", result.getLatency());
                    Log.i("server", result.getCountryLong());
                    Log.i("server", result.getCountryShort());

                    data.add(result.getCountryLong());
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    flagLink.add("http://v4v.info/countryflag/" + result.getCountryShort().toLowerCase() + ".png");
                }

                //Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + flagLink);

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), data, flagLink);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ServerResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

This is working for another version of android like android API 24 and others but not in Android 9(Pie) and Android Oreo (8.1). I want to run this in the Android 9(Pie) and Oreo (8.1).

Comment: What error you get to call `call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>()` ?

Comment: Specifically, there is no error in the logcat. But showing this line everytime

```E/libc: Access denied finding property "sys.thermal.para"```

Comment: Have you added `Retrofit2` libraries properly?

Comment: This code is working in another android device and emulator. Hope setup is ok.

Comment: if the error not showing in the logcat, try to restart android studio, and clear cache by clearing the project and rebuild it.

Comment: I did it many more times. But not working.

Comment: Any solution @ShahadatHossain ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your manifest file.

`<application...>
   <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
</application>`

it's helped for me for android API 24+. try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **NOT** using `https`, you can try my solution
in `Manifest`, add this line to `application` tag

```
<application...>
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
</application>
```

then file `network_security_config.xlm` could be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: What should be the replacement of   ```Trust user added CAs while debuggable only?``` 


**Not working for me.**

Comment: just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but this worked for me.

Add this to your manifest:

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

I think is because Android 9 + disables cleartext traffic by default so you need that if you are using retrofit

Comment: I have used this at that time. But it didn't work for me.